# Webmin - Setting up multiple virtual hosts - Subdomains

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, webmin

Can someone please help me in using WEBMIN to setup virtual hosts.

1. My current domain www.MYDOMAINLOLFAKE.com currently functions.

Settings are as follows -

Apache -
Handles the name-based server www.MYDOMAINLOLFAKE.com on all addresses
Address Any
Port 80 Server Name www.MYDOMAINLOLFAKE.com
Document Root /var/www/html

BIND DNS Server -
Master Zone
MYDOMAINLOLFAKE.com
ns1.mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE - works
ns2.mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE - works
mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE - works
www.mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE -works
mail.mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE - works
ftp.mydomainlolfake.com IPHERE - works

What I need -
something.mydomainlolfake.com -- CANT GET THIS TO WORK

What I tried -
Create new virtual host
Handles the name-based server something.mydomainlolfake.com on something.mydomainlolfake.com
Address Any
Port 81
Document Root: /var/www/vhosts/something

What happens - 
I create the new VHOST and then ALL address try to go to that new Document root. I need different addresses to go to their respective folders. Can someone please give me better instructions on how to set that up using webmin?

TLDR#
How do I make a something.mydomainlolfake.com subdomain work in webmin on my CENTOS 6 web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handles all requests to the address seopanel.mydomainlolfake.com:*.
Address seopanel.mydomainlolfake.com:*
Port Any    Server Name seopanel.mydomainlolfake.com
Document Root /var/www/vhosts/seopanel

The above settings inside Apache Management in Webmin allowed me to accomplish what I needed. I can now serve 2 separate virtual hosts.